# Javascript Array manipulation and looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

Output of the following code is given after the program. I need to iterate j value in the following order (1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,1),(3,4,1,2),(4,1,2,3) but it is in order of(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4),(3,4),(4) . Any help is much appreciated

```
var RRIntervalArrayDiff = [];
var validRRIntervalCount =0;
var RRIntervalArrayy = [0.62,0.65,0.40,2.54,0.65];
var n = RRIntervalArrayy.length;
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    for (j=i+1; j<n ;j++){
        document.write("</br>");
        document.write("i is "+i+" j is "+j);
        var h = (RRIntervalArrayy[j] - RRIntervalArrayy[i]);
        document.write("</br>");
        if(h < 0.12){
            validRRIntervalCount++;
        }
        document.write(h);
        if(j==(n-1)){
            document.write("</br>");
            document.write(validRRIntervalCount)
            break;
        }
    }    
    validRRIntervalCount = 0;
    document.write("</br>");
}
```

output

i is 0 j is 1
0.030000000000000027

i is 0 j is 2
-0.21999999999999997

i is 0 j is 3
1.92

i is 0 j is 4
0.030000000000000027

3

i is 1 j is 2
-0.25

i is 1 j is 3
1.8900000000000001

i is 1 j is 4
0

2

i is 2 j is 3
2.14

i is 2 j is 4
0.25

0

i is 3 j is 4
-1.8900000000000001

1

Comment: In the second for loop, you are not incrementing n value. You can try 

 for (j=i+1; j< n+1 ;j++){

Comment: Your array has 5 values

Answer (score 0):

You need to set j as 0 when it comes to the end of the array. And the double loop is useless.

```
var i=0;
var j=i;
for(i=0; i<arrayLength ; i++){
    j++;
    if(j==arrayLength){
        j=0;
    }
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing complex looping, you can just shift your element from start to end.

**RRIntervalArrayy.push(RRIntervalArrayy.shift());**

```js
var RRIntervalArrayDiff = [];
var validRRIntervalCount =0;
var RRIntervalArrayy = [0.62,0.65,0.40,2.54,0.65];
var n = RRIntervalArrayy.length;
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
document.write("--------------------------------");
document.write("</br>");
    for (j=0; j<n ;j++){
        document.write("</br>");
        document.write("array element is:" + RRIntervalArrayy[j] );
        var h = (RRIntervalArrayy[j] - RRIntervalArrayy[i]);
        document.write("</br>");
        if(h < 0.12){
            validRRIntervalCount++;
        }
        document.write(h);
        if(j==(n-1)){
            document.write("</br>");
            document.write(validRRIntervalCount)
            break;
        }
    }
   
    RRIntervalArrayy.push(RRIntervalArrayy.shift());
    validRRIntervalCount = 0;
    document.write("</br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to print in the order you need, try this:

```js
var RRIntervalArrayDiff = [];
var validRRIntervalCount =0;
var RRIntervalArrayy = [0.62,0.65,0.40,2.54,0.65];
var n = RRIntervalArrayy.length;
  var revert = 0;
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
  revert = 0;
     for (j=i+1; j< n ;j++){
       if(revert == 1 && j == i){
         break;
       }else if(revert == 1 && j != i){
        document.write(j + 1);
         continue;
       }
        document.write(j);
        if(j==(n-1)){
          if(revert == 0){
            j = -1;
            revert = 1;
          }
        }
    }    
    validRRIntervalCount = 0;
    document.write("</br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To strictly do what you want:

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
  var j = i + 1
  var count = 0
  while (count < n-1){
    if (j == n)
      j = 1
    // do your stuff
    count++
    j++
  }
// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of modulus magic can do he Job for you

```
var RRIntervalArrayDiff = [];
var validRRIntervalCount = 0;
var RRIntervalArrayy = [0.62, 0.65, 0.40, 2.54, 0.65];
var n = RRIntervalArrayy.length;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = i; j < n + i; j++) {
    var newJ = j % (n) + 1;
    //use newJ instead of j in your calculations
  }
}
```